# Swift Firebase : How to add on new questions to the list?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Currently this app has a `textfield` and when you press return on the keyboard it displays the live data on the screen but It deletes the previous question. My question is how can I not delete the previous question and just add this new question to the list. Thank you so much!

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseFirestore

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
    
    let database = Firestore.firestore()
    
    private let label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        return label
        
    }()
    
    private let field: UITextField = {
        let field = UITextField()
        field.placeholder = "enter text.."
        field.layer.borderWidth = 1
        field.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        return field
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(label)
        view.addSubview(field)
        field.delegate = self

        let docRef = database.document("ios/ex")
        docRef.addSnapshotListener {[weak self] snapshot, error in
            guard let data = snapshot?.data(), error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            guard let text = data["text"] as? String else {
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.label.text = text
            }
        }
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        field.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: view.safeAreaInsets.top+10, width: view.frame.size.width-20, height: 50)
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 1, y: view.safeAreaInsets.top+10+60, width: view.frame.size.width-20, height: 100)
    }
    
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if let text = textField.text, !text.isEmpty {
            savedData(text: text)
        }
        return true
    }
    
    func savedData(text: String){
        let docRef = database.document("ios/ex")
        docRef.setData(["text": text])
    }
    
}
```

Comment: There's no code in the question to indicate you're working with any kind of list. The code has a single label `private let label: UILabel` and a textField `private let field: UITextField`. as a side node this `DispatchQueue.main.async` is not needed in Firebase closures as UI calls are always done on the main thread, networking is done on a background thread.

Comment: could you help me please jay ? :/ I'm very new to this

Comment: We can help but need to understand what's being asked. *It deletes the previous question* - what does 'previous question' mean here? From what I can see, the user types data into a text field, that data is saved into Firebase, which then fires an event containing what the user just typed which then updates a label with that text. The code in your question works correctly for me so can you clarify what the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

save array in your "text" key instead of just string, and update array using this Firebase method called FieldValue.arrayUnion('your new value')